# Email not being shown as HTML even with IsBodyHtml property as true

Tags: c#, email, .net-core, html-email

I have found a lot of open questions about this issue, but none gave me a solution, so I am kind of re-opening other questions here, sorry.

I have an HTML created (from a VB6 application, though that's not very important because I checked it is correctly formatted) and then sent from a .NET Core worker application.

The `IsBodyHtml` property is being set to `true`, so it should work correctly.

The HTML I have generated has this structure:

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"> Resultado </th>
                <th>Índice del vector</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiempo inicio</td>
                <td class="centered">{DateTime}</td>
                <td class="centered">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiempo fin</td>
                <td class="centered">{DateTime}</td>
                <td class="centered">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiempo total</td>
                <td class="centered">{DateTime(Tiempo fin - Tiempo inicio)}</td>
                <td class="centered">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tipo de bases de datos</td>
                <td class="centered">{"SQL" | "Access"}</td>
                <td class="centered">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Copia de Documentos</td>
                <td class="centered">{ True | False }</td>
                <td class="centered">5</td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td>Carpeta no existente</td>
                <td class="centered">"TextMessage"</td>
                <td class="centered">11</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }

        table,
        td {
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }

        th, 
        td {
            padding: 5px;
            inline-size: 7rem;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
        }

        thead,
        tfoot {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            
        }

        .centered {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
```

I checked [the Gmail references](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#example_2) and it should work since the `<style>` tag is now supported (I think the only thing that is not very well supported is the `font-family` property), but it still was sent as raw HTML.

Then I tried sending a simple `<h1>This is an H1 element</h1>`, and it was still not shown correctly, just as raw HTML.

I also tried sending the former HTML with the `<body>` tag and the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` tag.

**[EDIT]**

Updated with the C# code for the e-mail sender:

```cs
private MailMessage SetMessageInfo(EmailService.MailMessage message)
        {

            MailMessage clientMessage = new Net_MailMessage();

            clientMessage.From = new MailAddress(message.From.Address, message.From.DisplayName);

            foreach (EmailService.MailAddress email in message.To)
            {
                clientMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Address, email.DisplayName));
            }
            foreach (EmailService.MailAddress email in message.CC)
            {
                clientMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(email.Address, email.DisplayName));
            }
            foreach (EmailService.MailAddress email in message.Bcc)
            {
                clientMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(email.Address, email.DisplayName));
            }

            clientMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            clientMessage.SubjectEncoding = message.SubjectEncoding;
            clientMessage.Body = message.Body;
            clientMessage.BodyEncoding = message.BodyEncoding;
            clientMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            if (message.CustomId != null)
            {
                clientMessage.Headers.Add("custom-id", message.CustomId);
            }

            return clientMessage;
        }
```

The `EmailService` class is an intermediary class we created that has a DTO that is almost a copy of the MailMessage class. I can't show it here, sorry.

Comment: Show us your code, without that we cannot help.

Comment: @DavidG Added the c# code. I thought it wasn't really necessary since I think the main problem is the `IsBodyHtml`. Sorry though.

Comment: What is `Net_MailMessage` and what do you do with it after this method? That's not a standard object in the framework. It looks like you have several layers of abstraction going on here so it's still impossible for us to figure out the problem.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, forgot to add `using Net_MailMessage = System.Net.Mail.MailMessage;`. It's just the standard MailMessage class.